# Ler dbase em PHP

Tags: php, dbase

Na empresa tem um software em Clipper, que salva as informações em dbase (banco_dados.dbf), agora surgiu a necessidade de integrá-lo com o PHP porém não consigo usar as funções dbase.
Já habilitei no php.ini a `extension=dbase.dll`, baixei a dll do seguinte endereço [link](https://pecl.php.net/package/dbase/5.1.0/windows) e coloquei na pasta ext. Porém ainda dá o seguinte erro: `Call to undefined function dbase_open()`.

Estou usando o Xampp com PHP versão 5.5.11.

Alguma ajuda ?

Comment: Qual versão do php está usando? thred safe ou não?

Comment: Estou usando o Xampp com PHP versão 5.5.11.

Comment: Eu fiz um teste aqui no php5.4, baixei o arquivo joguei a dll na pasta ext, adicionei a linha `extension=php_dbase` no php info, reinicie o servidor e funcinou([ver a imagem](http://i.stack.imgur.com/CU69g.png). Essa versão do php/xampp é 32bits ou 64bits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A versão da extensão que você baixou deve ser *incompatível* com a versão instalada do PHP. A extensão deve ser *thread-safe* e a versão do teu PHP não, ou *vice-versa*, o que ocasiona o erro mencionado por você:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Execute o [`phpinfo`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.phpinfo.php) e verifique se sua versão é ou não *thread-safe*:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

De acordo com a versão e a arquitetura, baixe a extensão correta do [*link*](https://pecl.php.net/package/dbase/5.1.0/windows) mencionado na pergunta.

Se você já colocou a linha `extension=php_dbase.dll` no arquivo `php.ini`, basta reiniciar o servidor e tentar novamente:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Estranho que na pergunta ele escreveu `extension=dbase.dll` ao invés de `extension=php_dbase.dll`, pode ser um dos problemas também

Comment: Ambas respostas complementaram a solução. Totalmente agradecido :)